# NGINX, set multiple certificates on same server_name

Tags: ssl, nginx

I would like to white labeling a site with SSL support for multiple different domain name like `site1.com`, `site2.com` etc.
I need for that to add multiples certs on the same `server_name`.
Do you know if it's possible and how to achieve that?

An example of what I want:

```
server {
  listen 443;
  server_name whitelabeling.example.com;

  # Key 1
  ssl_certificate /var/www/ssl/cert1.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /var/www/ssl/key1.key;
  # Key 2
  ssl_certificate /var/www/ssl/cert2.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /var/www/ssl/key2.key;
  #Key 3  
  ...
}
```

Comment: You will need to use a separate `server` block for each certificate and set the `server_name` to the clients domain name. Presumably you are using their DNS to point to your website.

Comment: Yes, they will create a `CNAME` pointing to ` whitelabeling.example.com`. I want to give to my clients the same server_name to set in DNS. It's not possible if I understand you ? Can you confirm me please.

Comment: `whitelabeling.example.com` is the A record that points to your server's IP address, it is not the value of the `server_name` directive.

Comment: Aaah ok, so when client will set this CNAME, the value of server_name will not be `whitelabeling.example.com` but their domain name. Ok, so my question make no sense right ?